# Finding the Candidate Keys of a Relation Using the FD's

Tags: relational-database, relation, relational-algebra, functional-dependencies, candidate-key

I have definitely checked out many different related posts, as suggested when creating this question. I have also done different sample problems from online sources as well from a similar problem. However, I am stuck on the problem below specifically.

Given the following relation R and the set of functional dependencies S that hold on R, find all candidate keys for R. Show your work.

```
R(A, B, C, D, E, F)
S:
AB → C

AC → B

AD → E

BC → A

E → F
```

Initially, I broke the attributes into groups:  attributes found only on the left, only on the right, and on both sides (they are D, ABCE, and F respectively). I also know that I should try to compute the closure of D. This is where I get stuck. At first glance, this seems like I am unable to solve this problem, which isn't true. I also tried computing the closures of (AD), (BD), (CD), and (ED) because I thought that the closure of D = D. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like CS homework, not a practical programming problem. cs.stackexchange.com may be a better place for it.

Comment: I understand, however there have been plenty of similar questions that weren't closed for this reason. They received some pretty great answers as well.

Comment: What *definiton* of CK in terms of FDs were you given and what *procedure* to find a CK from FDs were you given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys here are **ABD**, **ACD** and **BCD**.

You were on the right track. After dividing the attributes in three groups, the attributes under *"only on the left"* list are always a part of the key. Here that attribute is D.

*"I also tried computing the closures of (AD), (BD), (CD), and (ED)"*

As you couldn't determine the key while taking attributes in groups of 2 you should have then tried making group of 3 attributes and check their closure.